# PHP: allowing upload of .php files for users, how do I prevent them from running?

Tags: php, security, permissions

I am allowing people to upload their project files, I've tightened my security but I just need to get to the simple point. How can I stop execution of any files in the subdirectories they're uploading too?

I'm thinking `.htaccess` but I'd need to generate one for each new subdirectory (I think), would I need to scrap my current code and use a `.php` file to send headers to force DL on the file instead of running?

What do you think is an easy and safe solution for this? It just uploads to a subdirectory like `uploads/~foo/bar.html` or something, it looks nice that way so it'd be nice if it can stay like that format.

Comment: Why the downvote? It may be a duplicate, but then search the original and vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `uploads/.htaccess`:

RemoveType application/x-httpd-php .php

This will work for all subfolders. Also make sure you don't parse .htaccess in the users folders. This can be done by `AllowOverride None` in the main server config, or it can be done by not allowing uploads of .htaccess files in the first place.

Comment: Thank you alot, I thought and did disallow .htaccess from being uploaded, but the allowoverride would add the safetly I'd like.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, how would I allow this to not effect upload.php I got in there? lol

Comment: Actually don't worry! I got a directory back one that has nothing in it, I'll place the scripts there.

Comment: So then what if the file name is `../../backdoor.php` ?  If you do this alone,  it can be bypassed.  You also have to check the file name, its just a variable in an HTTP request that can be any value.

Answer (score 0):

If for example these uploaded files are in the directory "uploads" and subdirectories of it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/uploads\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```